# Views Template for first Block being applied to all

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a View called News which has about 10 different block displays in it serving various roles. I created a template for the first block (not block_1 and not the master) in order to apply some unique structure.

Though the changes are seen on all the blocks in News.

Based on the template suggestions for the block I need it to apply to, it suggests the following.

**Display output: views-view.tpl.php, views-view--news.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--block.tpl.php, views-view--news--block.tpl.php**

I'm using views-view--news--block.tpl.php since its the most granular of the options.

Is there another I should use?

Comment: Does it work with the ID of the block display instead? e.g. if the display ID is block_1, the template might be views-view--news--block-1.tpl.php

Comment: That's what I mentioned in the OP, it's not block_1, just block. The following view is block_1 which I don't want to touch.

Comment: So machine wise it goes default,block,block_1,and so on. So hitting "block" as the machine name is apparently applying to all blocks in the view versus just that one. basically there should be a block_0 option.

Comment: Oh sorry, must not have read it properly. You’ll have to implement hook_preprocess_view and manually remove that suggestion where it’s not wanted, `block` is a hard coded display type ID in Views, and your desired display ID conflicts with it - Views has no natural way for you to tell it that you don’t want the standard template naming to apply in that instance, so you have to override it

Comment: Oh, it sounds like maybe Views set the ID to `block` as standard, that wasn't something you changed? In that case there must be an easier way, I'm sure a bug like that wouldn't have been left unfixed for so long. I'll have a peek at the code

Comment: *head smack* I forgot that you can simply change the machine name in the display settings. So i just named it block_0, and voilà

Comment: Ohhh, I thought you had a requirement to leave it as `block`. Yeah changing the ID is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changing the machine name setting on the display allows me to make it what I want, so I gave it the machine name block_0 and now I can make a designated template for it.